# Visual Studio 2019 crash doing literally anything conntected to Windows Forms Designer Package (?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

I wanted to get VS Community 2019 after using 2017 for some time because i still had it.
Uninstalled VS2017 and installed VS2019
Now, i have done this today and tried reinstalling 2 times now.

My issue is: When i open VS2019 everything is normal. It is showing me all the options you have in the splashscreen, i can click on "Continue without code" without a problem. But if i try to open a .sln file, the Import Export Settings, create a new Project or open options the program crashes without a message, sometimes i get one. It is telling me:

> The "Windows forms designer package" packe did not load correctly... (pointing me to an xml for logs)

I open the Activity Monitor Log and at place 643, ERROR:

> CreateInstance failed for package [Windows Forms Designer
> Package]Source: 'mscorlib' Description: Exception has been thrown by
> the target of an invocation.
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
> by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could
> not load type 'System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxService' from assembly
> 'System.Drawing.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral

And so on..

GUID: {7494682B-37A0-11D2-A273-00C04F8EF4FF}
HR: 80004005 - E_FAIL
Source: VisualStudio

I can't really figure out how to fix this, any tips or ideas are appreciated.

Thank you in advance, even if it doesn'T work. Trying is everything!

Comment: I have never felt as bad as hitting "Update Windows" and then have it working.

Answer (score 0):

I updated windows until there were no more updates and rebooted my pc a couple of times, now it works.